# Oracle Columns mutually exclusive

Tags: oracle, triggers

Suppose a table called Mytable with two columns C1, and C2.
I want to have these two columns Mutually Exclusive.

I mean, if i enter value in one column C1 of this row in this table, db should not allow entry in C2 and viceversa.

in anycase, one of the column should be allowed to have data, not both(except NULL Values in both).

Is it possible either via creating triggers for this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I mean, if i enter value in one column C1 of this row in this table, db should not allow entry in C2 and viceversa.
>   in anycase, one of the column should be allowed to have data, not both(except NULL Values in both).

Something like that maybe ?

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name CHECK ((c1 is null and c2 is null) or
                                      (c1 is not null and c2 is null) or
                                      (c1 is null and c2 is not null))
```

Using a [Karnaugh map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) or simple logic, you can rewrite that as:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name CHECK (not (c1 is not null and c2 is not null))
```

This is is fact explicating that the only invalid combination is *"having a value both for c1 and c2"*.

Comment: Thanks Sylvain and Juergen , That helps a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name CHECK (c1 is null or c2 is null)
```

Comment: This way it will allow me to insert data in both the columns. I want to have data in only one of the columns not both. Like if C1 has data, then C2 should never be allowed to insert/update data. if C2 has data, then C1 should never be allowed to insert/update data. if both are NULL, that is fine.